# Count today's records

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I need to count only today's records

```
   public function sales()
{

    $h = Carbon::now(); 
    $recordstoday = Eventos::All();


    $data = [
        'category_name' => 'dashboard',
        'page_name' => 'sales',
        'has_scrollspy' => 0,
        'scrollspy_offset' => '',
    ];

    return view('dashboard',compact('recordstoday','h'))->with($data);
}
```

right now it counts all, but i need you to count today's records, to get today use Carbon

```
 <h4 class="card-text text-center"><b>{{$turnoshoy->count('created_at')}}</b></h4>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count using `whereDate`

```
ModelName::whereDate('created_at',now())->count();
```

for getting current month

```
$carbon=Carbon::now();

    ModelName::whereBetween('created_at',[
                                           $carbon->startOfMonth()->toDateString(),
                                           $carbon->endOfMonth()->toDateString()
                                      ])->count();
```

Comment: Thank you, if I wanted to count the records of a month, how ?

Comment: @user13523236 is it current month ?

Comment: also to get a dynamic month for example August

Comment: @user13523236. i have added sollution in my answer

Comment: can I count the column "asistencias" only those of today? using updated_at $asistencias = Eventos::whereNotNull('asistencia')->count();

Answer (score 0):

just use Carbon::today()

```
$recordstoday = Eventos::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();
```

Comment: can I count the column "asistencias" only those of today? using updated_at         
     $asistencias = Eventos::whereNotNull('asistencia')->count();

Comment: if you want column 'asistencias' which are updated today:
    Eventos::select('asistencias')->whereNotNull('assistencias')->whereDate('updated_at', 
    Carbon::today)->count();